# Scheduling a Task in Railo

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks, railo

I recently decided to move one of my simpler apps over to Railo.  So far so good.

One Problem, it's a scheduled task.  How/where does one set them up?  Under Railo Express I clicked in Tasks under both administrator and web admin sites, and no dice.. It only seems to show tasks which did not exceed ala an exception list.  I just want something to run once a week.

Having aptly moulded a [Google Query](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&q=scheduled+tasks+in+%2Brailo), I didn't have much luck so I figure others may come across this too.

Hoping for an embarrassingly quick reply, thanks!

**Update 1:** [Cfschedule](http://wiki.getrailo.org/wiki/3-1-Tags:CFSchedule) exists, I'd like the web frontend if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Railo *Web* Administrator (Not the *Server* Administrator), look in the left-hand navigation under Services. For me, the last one is "Scheduled Tasks" and from here, I can create and manage scheduled tasks.

I'm running Railo 3.0.2.001

Comment: I'll dig up my version and a screenshot.  I am pretty sure I am on v3.0.1

Comment: Adam, that was it.  I thought I was in the Web Administrator, but I wasn't.

It's there exactly as you described.. and it should be.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, having separate "Web" and "System" administrators can be a bit confusing at times.